# Feature learning: is it possible that AEs are better then VAEs?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I'm trying to use unsupervised feature learning for signal data, and I first experimented with an Autoencoder. I used the learned features at the bottleneck as features for supervised classification, and got satisfactory results. I then changed the architecture to that of a VAE, but I can't reach the same level of performance on supervised tasks as the regular autoencoder.

I don't think there's a problem with my VAE code as I just copied it off of GitHub repos (cross-checked it with multiple codes). The mean and STD of the produced latent variables Z do converge to somewhere around 0 and 1 (KLD Loss is far from 0 though). However, it seems that as the KLD decreases, the performance also worsens. It was my intuition that if it can reconstruct the input and decrease the KLD, then it's learning "meaningful" features in the latent space that are continuously getting "precise" (i.e. disentangled), and hence better for supervised tasks. However, this seems not to be the case.

Can someone help me understand what's happening? How can I at least achieve the performance of a regular AE through a VAE (my goal is not reconstruction but I want to explore the more-or-less disentangled features that can be learned by a VAE)? Or is this the part where I move on to InfoVAEs as they're supposedly better at learning features?

Answer (score 0):

All of your results will depend on the number of dimensions at the bottleneck, so whether this is 2D, 3D, and so on will affect the results.  AEs also need to take scale into consideration (normalization, mean-zero standardization, etc) since you can't feed an AE raw feature values from features with e.g. range [-500,500] and features with range [0,1] at the same time -- as feature range needs to be similar.

AE results will also change drastically with different datasets, so anything you discover regarding performance with the current data won't likely have anything to do with performance from another dataset.

You just need to evaluate performance as a function of transformations to overcome scale issues of features, and the dimensions used at the bottleneck.  No one can say which is going to be better for anything you are doing, since everything depends on feature range and scale, and dimensions used.